# How to use a global parent selector with CSS Modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules

I'm using [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) within a React application. I also have a [dropdown component](https://github.com/Fauntleroy/react-simple-dropdown) with some global styles (which I'm happy with, as the general styles I want to re-use).

When the dropdown is active, a CSS class is applied (`.dropdown--active`). Is there a way I can include that global class alongside my component's locally scoped styles? i.e., what I'd like is for this to work:

```
.myClass {
  color: red;
}

:global .dropdown--active .myClass {
  color: blue;
}
```

However, that syntax makes the entire selector global, which is not what I'm after: I want `.myClass` to be scoped to the component.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

just include the desired global class in parens:

```
:global(.dropdown--active) .myClass {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks, not sure how I missed that in the docs (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#exceptions)